# Javascript: Vertical Spacing between two elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website consists of a navigation bar (class `.nav-primary`), a widget box (id `#mw-panel`) and an article. Recently, I tried to move the widget box up to the top, by applying the following changes to my CSS file:

```
.mw-panel{top: 50px;}
```

The problem with this option was, that my element was fixed to a specific position. Instead I wanted the widget element to be exactly 100px under the menu bar (and moving when I am scrolling down the page). Instantly, I knew that JavaScript would be the correct way to solve this problem.

Because I had no success, I asked the [StackOverflow community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34596371/), which helped me a lot.

The JavaScript code in the JS section of the attached code snippet, was partially done by me, but it does not work as it should.

Can someone explain me what I need to change to get this JS code working? Again, `#mw-panel` has to be positioned exactly 100px beneath `.nav-primary`.

```js
var menu = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-primary")[0];
var widget = document.getElementById("mw-panel");
var difference = widget.offsetTop - menu.offsetBottom;
if (difference > 100) {
document.getElementById("mw-panel").style.top = (menu.offsetBottom + 100) + "px";
}
```

```css
.content .entry {
    margin-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 400px;
}
```

```html
<body class="full-width-content">

  <link rel="stylesheet" id="child-theme-css" href="http://vocaloid.de/wp-content/themes/Vuturize/style.css" type="text/css" >
  <div class="site-container">
    <nav class="nav-primary">
      <div class="wrap">
        <ul class="menu genesis-nav-menu menu-primary">
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">News</a>
          </li>
          <li class="menu-item"><a href="#">Ranking</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <div class="site-inner">
    <div class="content-sidebar-wrap">
      <main class="content">
        <article class="page entry">
<div>
          <h1>Test Article</h1>
          </div>
        </article>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="mw-panel">
    <div>
      <h3>Navigation</h3>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Letzte Änderungen</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

      <h3>Werkzeuge</h3>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Datei hochladen</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Spezialseiten</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Try and add the `<script>` tag after all your DOM elements, just before `</body>`. Your script might not be loading the DOM properly, which is why it can't find `#mw-panel`

Comment: Or place script as described in [document ready equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

Comment: @AlexL I guess this is not causing the problem. I added the JS code in the right section of the stackoverflow code editor, so it should be automatically positioned at the end by default. When watching the running code snippet in full view, you can see it is not moved to the top..

Comment: @OtakuKyon Chrome doesn't report any errors when I run your snippet though, can you verify the error is gone?

Comment: @AlexL After moving the code to the end of </body> tag fixed the DOM error, but the script is still not working

Comment: Try removing the `[0]` after `getElementById("mw-panel")`

Comment: @AlexL Removed it, checked the updated website, and no sucess

Comment: @AlexL I updated the source code

Comment: why not re-arrange your html and put the #mw-panel 50px  below your menubar ......also do you want your menubar AND mw-panel box to move together when you scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's No such property as `offsetBottom`. Redo your code ONLY considering `offsetTop` + `offsetHeight` to get bottom number.

Example:

```
var menu = document.getElementsByClassName("nav-primary")
var TrueOffset=menu[0].offsetTop+menu[0].offsetHeight;
```

You're getting the error because there is no `offsetBottom` property.

Do `console.log(menu)` in chrome to see the objects available properties

**Update:

Add this to your css:

```
.mw-panel{
position: absolute;  
  }
```

[Here it is in action](https://jsfiddle.net/jj6jn7b1/)

[Updated code in action](https://jsfiddle.net/jj6jn7b1/2/)

Comment: I opened the updated code and added the CSS file, but it did not seem to work, because the widget box is still on the bottom of the page.

Comment: You have to add the .mw-panel class to the div... `<div id="mw-panel" class="mw-panel">`  I'll update the code

Comment: Updated in jsfiddle, in your final code change the class name so it's not the same as the id.. mw-panel

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading your question, I missed one key detail: you're trying to do this JavaScript. This is your problem.

If I understand correctly, you have three items: a nav, an article, and a widget box. You want the widget box to stand 100px below the nav, and then move with the page when you scroll.

if this is the case (if not, correct me), then there's only a few things you need to do:

1. Keep your nav the way it is. Good job here.
2. I'm assuming you want the widget next to the article (on the left?). So you'll need to make two columns (some sort of containers, each `height: 100%`). Your widget container will have the property `position: fixed;` and the article will have `position: static;` (or `relative`, you decide).
3. Each container will have a width, you might choose 30% for the widget container and 70% for the article, for example.
4. Now you have two columns, one will move with the page as you scroll.

Here are some links to get you started:

[Best Way to do Columns in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966890/best-way-to-do-columns-in-html-css)

https://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/

http://www.456bereastreet.com/lab/developing_with_web_standards/csslayout/2-col/

Comment: Probably my issue explanation was a bit misleading. When writing about 'moving when scrolling the page' I was refering to the css code I posted above. '.mw-panel{top: 50px;}' >fixes< the position of the widget. It will always have a distance of 50px from the top of the browser to the widget. But this is not what I want. Instead I want to make it scrollable. When I scroll down the page, the navigation moves upwards and the widget has to follow the navigation bar, but has to keep a distance of 100px.

Comment: Summarized: The problem is caused by the JavaScript code, which is not working as it should.

Comment: It would help if you had an example website to model the design off of, I'm still having a hard time figuring out *why* JavaScript is necessary.